# WSO2 AM curl command to add roles

Tags: curl, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use curl to add roles and users to carbon. I followed the steps from here: http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/

That allowed me to be able to use soapUI to do it. But when I try to use curl I can not get it to work. Here is my curl command:

```
curl -k --basic -u "admin:admin" --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @soaprole.xml https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint
```

I get the following error:

```
<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>
```

And this is my xml file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://dao.service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:addRole>
<ser:roleName>creator</ser:roleName>
<ser:permissions>
<xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
 <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/Manage/API</xsd:resourceId>
     </ser:permissions>
     <ser:permissions>
        <xsd:action>ui.execute</xsd:action>
        <xsd:resourceId>/permission/admin/login</xsd:resourceId>
     </ser:permissions>
  </ser:addRole>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo in my curl command that was causing the problem. This is what I am using now and it is working:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -k --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:addRole" -d @soaprole.xml --url https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you access `RemoteUserStoreManagerService`? Make sure to enable `<hideadminservicewsdl>` option at carbon.xml , and try to access above service's wsdl from your browser.

eg:`https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl`  should display the admin service wsdl.

Comment: Yes the wsdl responds correctly. And I made sure the admin service was enabled per the url in my question.

Comment: Any other idea's on what to check?

Comment: The error clearly says it could not find the endpoint. Do you have any server level error logs? Check wso2carbon.log file.